# SVG transform only on path coordinates not lines and thickness

Tags: svg

as I understand, svg transformations such as scaling apply to the whole svg object, I.e. not only to vector-points, but also to thickness and width of lines. I.e. a `transform= "scale(10)" operation means, that the line width is 10 times thicker than without this transform.

Is there a way to apply such a transformation to vertices of the paths only? I would like to keep consistent path widths.

Lets say I have the following SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<polygon transform="scale(10) translate(100,100)" style=" fill: rgba(255,255,255,0);  stroke: black; " points=" 100.0,0.0 49.99999999999997,86.60254037844388 -49.99999999999998,86.60254037844388 -100.0,1.2246467991473532E-14 -49.999999999999964,-86.60254037844388 49.999999999999936,-86.6025403784439 100.0,-2.4492935982947064E-14" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, set vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" That will work on Opera, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. There's an [example here](http://schepers.cc/svg/vectoreffects/nonscalingstroke.svg).

Comment: This is not working in Chrome (v47) if the transform is not reversible like scale(0,2). I have not checked in other browsers.

Comment: Well the UA has to do an inverse scale so that's pretty much expected. If you have a scale like that you won't see any scaled drawing.

Comment: This is what I guess, but this dependent on the implementation and is not what the [specification says](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke).

Comment: No, it is **not**. Ellipse can degenerate to segment. And applying `scale(0,2)` to `"M0 0 H 1"` doesn't change the path. There is no reason that a projection applied to a path "smash" the line width. And all this is not consistent with the fact that `scale(0.00001,2)` is completely different from `scale(0,2)` when used with `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`. And on top of that, this behavior is not consistent with the specifications.

Comment: Update (2023): you can find the vector-effect MDN page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect); The MDN page has no info on browser support, but according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/vector-effect) it's supported in all major browsers these days.